# Swing GUI: drawString - How to set the font size of the String being displayed?

Tags: java, swing, font-size, paintcomponent

We all know that the drawString method can be used this way:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Heading");
        frame.setSize(1000,500);
        myComponent comp = new myComponent();
        frame.add(comp);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class myComponent extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawString("Hello World", 300, 300);
    }
}
```

But, how do we adjust the font size of the string being displayed? I want to make it larger.

Answer (score 4):

```
class myComponent extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int fontSize = 20;
        Font f = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, fontSize);
        g2.setFont(f);
        g2.drawString("Hello World", 300, 300);
    }
}
```

You can change the style, size and Font because you probably don't want to use Comic Sans.

See also [`Graphics#setFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setFont-java.awt.Font-).

Answer (score 4):

> how do we adjust the font size of the string being displayed?

You can derive a new Font based on the current font:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g); // don't forget this.
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // make sure the background is cleared

    Font font = g.getFont().deriveFont( 20.0f );
    g.setFont( font );
    g.drawString(...);
}
```

You don't need a Graphics2D object to draw a string.

Or instead of forcing the Font to be a specific size in the paintComponent() method you can customize your object by using:

```
MyComponent comp = new MyComponent();
comp.setFont( comp.getFont().deriveFont( 20.0f );
```

In this case you use your current painting code.

Also, class names should start with an upper case character you your class should be "MyComponent".

Comment: `super.paintComponent(g); `  Why is this used mate?

Comment: In the general case is you used to invoke the default painting code for the component. For example, a JPanel will just paint the background of the panel. When you extend JComponent, it probably doesn't matter if you use this or not, but it is a good idea to always do this. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.